# why gradle attemps to download appcompat again

Tags: android, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

Why gradle trys to download dependencies again, when it downloaded them in past?

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.androied.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    //compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile project(':sweetsheet')
    compile files('libs/bolts-tasks-1.3.0.jar')
}
```

the error:

```
Error:(30, 13) Failed to resolve: com.androied.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1
<a href="openFile:F:/projects/AndroidStudio/Samadie/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

I'm not online all the time. I downloaded the appcompat-v7:
[screenshot of downloaded appcompat-v7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20Oal.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo.

`com.androi e d.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1` instead of

`com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

You can change gradle settings in the android studio

Go to settings and type gradle then you can tick gradle offline work and the gradle is not going download dependencies every time.

Comment: I did that. I had an stupid mistake in writing the name of dependency.